# mocha-webpack - dom is not updating

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

I am using Vue with Webpack4. And I was installed `mocha-webpack` for test. But I got a result of failed from Mocha. I think to `count` is updating, so I think to pass to test. But failed. Why I got a result like this? Maybe, VirtualDom is not updating on running of test.  `increment` method was called on test, But not updated dom.

Test result.

```
 MOCHA  Testing...



  Counter.vue
    1) increments count when button is clicked


  0 passing (26ms)
  1 failing

  1) Counter.vue
       increments count when button is clicked:
     Error: expect(received).toMatch(expected)

Expected substring: "1"
Received string:    "0"
      at Context.it (/path/to/project/static/bundles/main-92a73207cfb074150def.js:7:220294)



 MOCHA  Tests completed with 1 failure(s)
```

setup.js

```
require('jsdom-global')();

global.expect = require('expect');

window.Date = Date;
```

Counter.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{ count }}</span>
    <button @click="increment()">Increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Counter.spec.js

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Counter from './Counter.vue'

describe('Counter.vue', () => {
  it('increments count when button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Counter);
    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('div span').text()).toMatch('1');
  });
});
```

package.json

```
    "jsdom": "^15.1.1",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "mocha-webpack": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
```

Comment: test test test test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you change `count` actual DOM is not updated at that moment. So you should wait until Vue manipulate the DOM, since Vue performs DOM manipulations asynchronously.

> For example, when you set `vm.someData = 'new value'`, the component
> will not re-render immediately. It will update in the next “tick”,
> when the queue is flushed. Most of the time we don’t need to care
> about this, but it can be tricky when you want to do something that
> depends on the post-update DOM state.

Exampel of code from `vue-test-utilds` docs:

```js
it('fetches async when a button is clicked', done => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo)
  wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
  wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.value).toBe('value')
    done()
  })
})
```

I have not worked with `mocha` but i assume that your code should look something like this:

```
describe('Counter.vue', done => {
  it('increments count when button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Counter);
    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.find('div span').text()).toMatch('1');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

[Async Update Queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue).

[Testing Asynchronous Behavior](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html#testing-asynchronous-behavior).